How does one show that a bounded monotone sequence of rational numbers is Cauchy without using the least upper bound property?
I am reading about the construction of the real number and one of the step when you construct the two sequences $\{l_{n}\}$ and $\{u_{n}\}$
as follows:
Defines $m_{n} = \frac{(l_{n} + u_{n})}{2}$. Then at each step,
If $m_{n}$ is an upper bound for $S$, set $u_{n+1} = m_{n}$, and $l_{n+1} = l_{n}$.
If $m_{n}$ is a lower bound for $S$, set $u_{n+1} = u_{n}$, and $l_{n+1} = m_{n}$.
The book claims that these two sequence are Cauchy and that all bounded monotone sequence of rational numbers is Cauchy and that it can be proven without the least upper bound property of $\mathbb{R}$. But I cannot see how this could be done. Any hints will be thankful!

Clarification request: Do you (just) want to see that this binary search is Cauchy? or do you want to see (the more general) a bounded monotone sequence in the rationals is Cauchy?

I want to see the more general version that a bounded monotone sequence in the rationals is Cauchy.

Assume that $x_n$ is a bounded monotone (w.l.o.g we can assume it is increasing) sequence then obviously there exists a $M>0$ such that $|x_n|<M$. What we would like to prove is that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N$ such that $m,n > N \Rightarrow |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$. Assume that is not true then there is a $\epsilon$ such that for all $N$, $|x_n-x_m|>\epsilon$ which results $|x_n-x_{n+1}|>\epsilon$ for all n. Also let $\lfloor (M-x_0)/\epsilon \rfloor=c$
$|x_{n+1}-x_n|>\epsilon \Rightarrow x_{n+1} > x_n+\epsilon$
$x_{n+1}>x_n+\epsilon \Rightarrow x_{n+2} > x_{x_n+1} + \epsilon > x_{n} + 2\epsilon$
Applying this repetitively we get $x_{n+c+1}>x_n + (c+1)\epsilon > x_n-x_0+M>M$ but that is a contradiction with $|x_k|<M$ for all k hence $x_n$ is Cauchy

If there is an $\epsilon$ such that for each $n$ you can find a pair of entries beyond $n$ that differ by more than $\epsilon$ then this monotone sequence has infinitely many gaps of at least $\epsilon$ so is not bounded.
